# What is this verb noun association called in linguistics?

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

Not all verbs work with all nouns.

It is better to say "fix errors" than "solve errors", for example.

In linguistics, is there a name for semantic compatibilities between nouns and verbs that go before them like this?

Comment: Questions about linguistics should be asked at the [linguistics.se] site.

Comment: Logically, errors are fixed and problems are solved. Sometimes (not always) semantics does seem to be logical.

Comment: 'Licensing' is the grammatical term. In "fix errors", the verb "fix" licenses "errors", but "sneeze" doesn't.

Comment: @BillJ isn't collocation like the answer suggests ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for  [collocation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/collocation):

> [ U ] the regular use of some words and phrases with others, especially in a way that is difficult to guess.

(Cambridge Dictionary )